# Can't boot Ubuntu 16.04 after latest update

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, graphics

Today I received an update  I installed it, rebooted my computer and can't boot it up now. See attached screen shot. Kernel Panic

Update History Log

```
Start-Date: 2018-01-10  15:54:50
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.85'
Install: linux-headers-4.4.0-108-generic:amd64 (4.4.0-108.131, automatic), linux-headers-4.4.0-108:amd64 (4.4.0-108.131, automatic), linux-image-4.4.0-108-generic:amd64 (4.4.0-108.131, automatic), linux-signed-image-4.4.0-108-generic:amd64 (4.4.0-108.131, automatic), linux-image-extra-4.4.0-108-generic:amd64 (4.4.0-108.131, automatic)
Upgrade: linux-headers-generic:amd64 (4.4.0.104.109, 4.4.0.108.113), linux-libc-dev:amd64 (4.4.0-104.127, 4.4.0-108.131), linux-image-generic:amd64 (4.4.0.104.109, 4.4.0.108.113), libcuda1-384:amd64 (384.90-0ubuntu0.16.04.2, 384.111-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), linux-signed-image-generic:amd64 (4.4.0.104.109, 4.4.0.108.113), skypeforlinux:amd64 (8.11.0.4, 8.13.0.2), linux-signed-generic:amd64 (4.4.0.104.109, 4.4.0.108.113), linux-generic:amd64 (4.4.0.104.109, 4.4.0.108.113), nvidia-opencl-icd-384:amd64 (384.90-0ubuntu0.16.04.2, 384.111-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), nvidia-375:amd64 (384.90-0ubuntu0.16.04.2, 384.111-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), nvidia-384:amd64 (384.90-0ubuntu0.16.04.2, 384.111-0ubuntu0.16.04.1)
End-Date: 2018-01-10  15:57:54
```

Comment: @N0rbert you've made my day. You have absolutely no idea how much I would pay you for this service! Thank you very much, you are a good man! I've fixed this problem. I need to grab a beer to cool down after all this :///